# Large memory use using content providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an app which monitors several content providers such as the calendar, contact list, gmail etc

The app is working fine, but I'm finding that it can be using up to about 70mb of memory. When I look in gingerbread at the memory use the app itself is using around 6-7mb and the rest is the content providers, so for example at the moment:

*Android Core App - 16mb - Provider Contacts is in use*

*Gmail - 36mb - Provider Gmail is in use*

*Calendar Storage 3.9mb - Provider Calendar is in use*

When I start the app up the memory usage is low, but as soon as for example I receive a gmail the memory shoots up.
When I'm querying the content providers I'm always making sure I close any cursors that are opened.

Is there something else I should be closing that I'm missing? I don't want to unregister the observer as I still want to be monitoring for changes in the future.

Comment: you do not have to worry about memory usage that originates by using content providers. They are held by android os, it is your operating systems responsibility.

Comment: I must admit I've not noticed it cause a problem, but when other similar apps are using a few megabytes of memory and mine is using 60/70mb people start asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my issue was using multiple cursors within one another. I've no idea why, but once I changed my code to perform a query, store the results in a collection, close the query and then iterate around that collection to perform the lower level query I'm now not seeing the really large memory useage.

I was closing the cursors of each at the earliest point possible with the way the code was written, but this way the query gets closed down sooner.